# How to save a replay?

Tags: clash-royale

I've recently had a (very) good game, and I want to save it to watch it at a later time.
**How can I save replays permanently?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is currently impossible ingame but you can:

- Record the replay with your device
- Maximise the amount of time the replay stays ingame by making your own clan, close it, then "share" your replay

Either you can maximize the amount of time it stays in game or you can record and keep the replay permently.

Comment: One note; replays are erased when there is an update, so the second option in not quite permanent.

Answer (score 0):

I just recorded myself watching a replay using the YouTube Gaming app and it's screencast function to record.